# Cookies throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Function below throw me `NullPointerException`

```
Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(req, CookieName.AUTHENTICATION);
```

How can I handle this exception?

Comment: I tried this on my machine. There was no error. Are you trying to use the "cookie" field which gives this error ?

Comment: yes, still stop me at this line(above)

Comment: Can you a few more  lines of your code here

Answer (score 0):

I think that your CookieName.AUTHENTICATION is null. After i've read library code that might be causing NPE.